# What compiler technology does jump label analysis and generation?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

I am working on a small compiler project which involves generating a jump label in the final code.

I am not sure what particular compiler technology, the problems belongs to and so, I am not even sure how to google references.

Hope you could point me a direction.

Here is the code to be compiled:

```
goto A

-- some optional code
-- may be here

A: if (2 > 1)
       print Y
   else
       print N
```

My input is AST of the above code:

```
Node if, label A
   child1 condition
      child11 expr 2 > 1
   child2 body
      child21 print Y
   child3 else
      child31 print N
```

The problem is, I need to propagate "label A" from "Node if" to "child11", before I the code generation phase.

I was thinking this is part of Static Single Assignment, SSA, analysis and transformation, after reading a lecture note, I do not see it.

Hope you can help out.

Comment: "I need to propagate "label A" from Node if to child11, before I do code generation." Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Short Answer**

Lookup for "intermediate code" generation phase, first. Some compilers doesn't use it, and don't documented. You will need it to implement "goto".

**Long Extended Answer**

The *goto*, *label* statements, are transformed in the *code generation* step, after the generation of the A.S.T.

Remember, that there are several techniques to built a compiler, or interpreter, and may vary from one project to another.

In this particular case, after the A.S.T., is built, an structure called "intermediate code", is built from the A.S.T.

Usually, is a list of simple instructions, with a single operation, and a few parameters.

```
(97) goto 100
(98) do something
(99) do something
(100) ifgreater 2, 1
(101) then print n
(102) else print y
```

Many code lines can be transform from the AST, to final code, "goto" doesn't.

If a label is declared after the "goto", you need to generate the "goto" as "goto temp1", as an intermediate instruction, generate the following lines, included where the label is declared.

```
(97) goto temp1
(98) do something
(99) do something
(100) ifgreater 2, 1
(101) then print n
(102) else print y
```

And later, return to replace the "temp1" with the real line number.

```
(97) goto 100
(98) do something
(99) do something
(100) ifgreater 2, 1
(101) then print n
(102) else print y
```

And, later, transform this intermediate code into final (object) code.

Comment: Can you correct the 2nd example? I think you missed "temp1" intermediate instruction.

Comment: @myquestion fixed both example and answer that describes Example

Comment: my question is actually towards the phase before your example code is generated. Because in AST, label is at the If node, somehow I need to propagate the label to its child node. Thanks for your examples though, it helps me a lot to clear up my mind.

Comment: It's not true that you need intermediate code to support gotos/labels. You can go directly from the AST to assembly just fine even if you support goto.

Comment: @sepp2k Good, you may want to add an answer, or link, for the user of the question